boxplot with facet_wrap for comparing datasets in R?
I have the following data.frame and i would like to boxplot the data comparing Obs vs Sim for Upstream and Downstream location. here is my sample code that is returning wrong plot.
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(999)

DF <-data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), to = as.Date("2003-12-31"), by = "day"),
                Ob = runif(1095,1,5), Sim = runif(1095,1,5)) %>% 
                filter(between(month(Date),3,10)) %>% 
                mutate(Gauge = rep("Upstream", 735)) %>% 
  rbind(data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), to = as.Date("2003-12-31"), by = "day"),
                   Ob = runif(1095,2,8), Sim = runif(1095,1,9)) %>% 
          filter(between(month(Date),3,10)) %>% 
          mutate(Gauge = rep("Downstream", 735))) %>% 
  mutate(Month = month(Date)) %>% 
  select(5,4,2,3)

DF_Long <- DF %>% pivot_longer(-c(Month,Gauge), names_to = "Variables", values_to = "Value")



ggplot(DF_Long, aes(x = Month, y = Value, col = Variables))+
  geom_boxplot(lwd=1, notch = TRUE) +
  facet_wrap(Gauge ~ ., nrow = 2, scales = "free_y")

Example: I want sort of below graph for upstream and downstream for June to October.


Try aes(x = factor(Month), y = Value, col = Variables), or aes(x = Month, y = Value, col = Variables, group = interaction(Month, Variables)) if you want to keep Month as a continuous variable.

That worked- Thanks
